# Creating multiple rules in Azure search Synonym map is not working

Tags: azure, full-text-search, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk, text-search

I am creating a synonym map like below,

```
{ "name": "country-synonym",
 "format":"solr",
 "synonyms": "germany, dl, deutschland\n 
 india, ind"
}
```

But when I queried the synonym to view it, it was created like below, instead of two rules, only one rule was created.

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://#############.search.windows.net/$metadata#synonymmaps/$entity",
"@odata.etag": "###########",
"name": "country-synonym",
"format": "solr",
"synonyms": "germany, dl, deutschland india, ind",
"encryptionKey": null
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Although it looks like it is creating only one rule, search works perfect for the two rules. So I guess, the response is a bit badly constructed

Answer (score 0):

You answered it correctly in your comment.  The search is working correctly, meaning the search terms were posted to the API correctly.  The problem is the browser collapsing the newline.  Try to look at the raw response in the Inspector & you should see the newline.